# Is this group a wreath product?

Tags: group-theory, wreath-product

Let $Z$ be a group and consider the symmetric group $S_n$ on $n$ elements. Assume we have an action $\phi$ of $S_n$ on $Z$ by automorphisms. Consider the group $K$ which is a direct product of $n$ copies of $Z$.

Consider now the action $\psi$ of an element $\sigma$ of $S_n$ on $K$ which sends a $n$-tuple $(z_1,z_2,...,z_n) \in K, z_i \in Z$ to $(f(z_1),f(z_2),...,f(z_n))$ where $f(z_i)=\phi_\sigma(z_{\sigma(i)})$ if $\sigma(i) \neq i$, and $f(z_i)=z_i$ if $\sigma(i)=i$.

Consider finally the semidirect product of $K$ by $S_n$, with the action $\psi$. My question is: is it a wreath product of $Z$ by $S_n$ ? Or is it a more general construction ?
I've tried considering building explicit isomorphisms to $Z \wr S_n$, but the action of $\phi$ is problematic.

Comment: Have you tried a simple example, like $n=2$, $Z=\mathbb Z$, and $S_2$ acting on $Z$ by the sign?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : I actually had an example with bigger groups and $n$=3. I checked with GAP and the resulting group has the same order as the wreath product, but I still don't know if they are isomorphic. In your example, the product $((0,0),\sigma)((p,q),1_{\mathbb{Z}_2})$ would be $((-q,-p),\sigma)$ so it seems that it would indeed be a wreath product. Or did I miss an obvious counterexample ? :)

Comment: It is obvious that your group and the wreath product hae the same cardinal in all cases! They are simply have the same underlying set. I do not see how you concluded from that equality that «it seems that it would indeed be a wreath product», really.

Comment: Are you sure that your map $\psi$ really is an action?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez :  I never said it would be a wreath product. I'm wondering if it is, and this is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Well, what I am suggesting is for you to pick a concrete example and try to see whether it is or not. Looking at the order will certainly not help with that, so I am further suggesting that you consider finer invariants —or that you try hard(er) to find an isomorphism.

Comment: In any case, if you have constructed the group in GAP, then why not use GAP to test whether it is isomorphic to the wreath product?